# Do I need to be under 26 at the time of booking or time of departure for SAS youth tickets?

Tags: air-travel, sweden, sas

Do I need to be under 26 at the time of booking or time of departure for SAS youth tickets? I am 25 but I will be 26 when I plan on going on this trip, do I still qualify for the youth rate?

Answer (score 5):

**You need to be under 26 at the time of departure.**

Source: Tweet by official SAS twitter account.

(Also @LassiUosukainen pointed out in a comment: If you enter the correct birth date the system does not let you continue if you are too old.)

Comment: Do you have the link to the tweet?

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely that you might be challenged, as you need to present your id in order to board with a [SAS Youth Ticket](https://www.flysas.com/en/fl/Promotions-and-prices/Youth/Youth/):

> Eligibility: Valid for youth 0-25 years of age. Youth under 12 years must travel with adult 16 years or older. Fare not valid for unaccompanied minors. Passengers must present a valid ID at the time of ticketing and at the gate.
>
> ID required: Valid passport must be provided as a proof of your age when boarding.

Visit [the SAS web site](http://www.flysas.com) and indicate your country location; selecting Contact offers the country-specific information to query the company directly and eliminate any uncertainty and possible interruption of your travel plans.

Comment: Furthermore, you can't book the flight if you enter your correct birth date. The system gives you a warning and doesn't let you continue if you're too old.

Comment: @LassiUosukainen I have included your comment in my answer (as comments can easily be deleted and I find it a precious piece of information). You might want to make it an answer in itself though and in that case I would delete the respective paragraph of my answer (and +1 yours).

Comment: @LassiUosukainen I agree with mts; make that an answer, and I'll upvote.